# What's the difference between "Strahl" and "Strahlung"?

Tags: meaning, difference, comparison

I wanted to write something like:

> Wir müssen die Sonnenstrahlen / Sonnenstrahlungen in Anspruch nehmen, weil man dadurch umweltfreundliche und nachhaltige Energie generieren kann.

I checked Duden for [Strahl](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Strahl?amp) and [Strahlung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Strahlung?amp), but I'm still not sure which one to use here, or are both ok?

Comment: Why did you not Post two or three examples showing "Strahl" and "Strahlung" in useful contexts?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin sorry if you found my question misleading in any way, the Duden hyperlinks above contain some useful examples.

Comment: Thanks and it's not your readers' job to figure out what links might lead to… It's your job to Post the examples. Who thinks I'm mistaken, please shout out here and now!

Luckily for you, some Members with wider knowledge ran with it.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Why would I post examples that I don't have problems with? I only posted one example, because this is the only example in which I didn't know which one of the two words to choose, posting more examples would've made my question unnecessarily long and could have diverted the attention away from the main example

Answer (score 11):

"Strahl" means ray and "Strahlung" means radiation. Notably "Strahlung" usually is uncountable and has no plural as it is the entirety of emitted rays, who jointly form the radiation (field); this argument holds both, in German and English. Sometimes the plural is used to describe different types of radiations, though in my experience phrased differently, like in "Strahlungsarten".

As to your example, the more ideomatic expression is "mit etwas Energie erzeugen":

> Wir müssen die Sonnenstrahlen / Sonnenstrahlung nutzen, weil man damit umweltfreundliche und nachhaltige Energie erzeugen kann.

"Sonnenstrahlung" is a bit unusual and one would rather use "die Strahlung der Sonne" or "der Sonnenschein"

Or leave out both:

> Wir müssen die Sonne in Anspruch nehmen, weil sie umweltfeundliche und nachhaltige Energie liefert.

Comment: The plural "Strahlungen" might (rarely) be used to mean "different kinds of radiation".

Comment: I pondered about that during writing the answer. While it could be formed that way, and it would be understood, I couldn't find it in my literature. It is always Strahlungsarten or similar.

Comment: I wonder how you go about counting the sun's rays?

Comment: Not sure why you say, „Sonnenstrahlung“ is a bit unusual.  In the given context, referring to the energy of the sun,„Sonnenstrahlung“ it’s definitely the most common way to say it (but note the singular).

Comment: "Strahlungen" by Ernst Jünger

Comment: @bakunin bei dem Titel würde ich eine leicht andere Bedeutung sehen, quasi als passive Substantivierung der Tätigkeit, Strahlung im Sinne ähnlich von gesandstrahlt werden etc. Das erste Mal als die erste Strahlung auf den Schlachtfeldern, das zweite Mal als die zweite etc. Der Titel spielt aber ganz klar mit verschiedenen interpretationen

Comment: @planetmaker: das war auch eher mit einem gewissen süffisanten Unterton gemeint. Der Titel "Mein gesammeltes Unvermögen, einen graden deutschen Satz zu stilisieren" wäre in Anbetracht des Inhalts dieses Machwerks eher angemessen.

Answer (score 2):

Conclusion: both are acceptable (as you assumed after consulting a dictionary)
Reasoning: in technical terms, you want to capture the energy of electromagnetic waves.
Now, Strahlung =^= radiation and Strahlen =^= rays
It is just a matter of style, regarding the target audience and kind of publication that is  intended: Strahlung is the more formal, Strahlen the more colloquial, even poetic style.

Comment: Sonnenstrahlung**en** is not acceptable though

Answer (score 1):

*Strahlung* only applies to energetic waves, (the composite *Ausstrahlung* has an entirely different meaning). For everything else, water from the tube or tap, coffee from the coffee pot just *Strahl* is correct.
It is worth to look up other reference works as well, such as [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Strahlung), which I consider quite complete.

Note, that we have an overlap in *Sonnenstrahl* which denotes a single distinct ray, while *Sonnen(ein)strahlung* and connected *UV-Strahlung* denote measurable physical units.